# Error 22 The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I cloned a project with vs 2013. When I run it I get this error.

```
Error   1   The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task could not be loaded from the assembly D:\BMaster\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.13\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\BMaster\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.13\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.   BargainMaster.Web
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm not sure about root cause of this issue but it appeared when I added missing libraries by hand.

I resolved it by doing this:

1. Delete `<solution>\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.13\`
2. Close solution
3. Open solution
4. Navigate to *View / Other Windows / Package Manager Console*
5. Press *Restore Packages* in right top corner of the window
6. Re-build

Comment: Edit: upgraded nuget, saw the button, but this didn't work for me :/

Comment: I'd try to move packages (to somewhere else) and run `nuget.exe restore path\to\my\solution.sln`

Comment: I had a conflicted config file that was causing the issue. Resolving the conflicts fixed everything nicely.

Comment: Yes!! tks my friend

Comment: This fixed my issue in Visual Studio Code w/ the C# (Omnisharp) plugin.

Answer (score 9):

*(For some reason none of the other answers worked for me.)*

I resolved the issue by doing this:

1. Delete the "packages" folder.
2. Right click on the solution > `Manage NuGet Packages or Solution`.
3. Downgrade `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` to a previous version 1.0.14. (Latest stable version at the moment of writing this is 1.0.21)
4. Restore packages and rebuild.

Comment: Using VS2019, my solution was similar: downgrade Microsoft.Bcl.Build to 1.0.14, build [SUCCESS!], upgrade back to 1.0.21 and build again [also SUCCESS!].

Comment: Yes, downgrading was the solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

I just went to the Manage NuGet packages options for the particular VS project and updated the version of the Microsoft BCL nuget and it solved the problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me in VS2019.  Updating from 1.0.14 to 1.0.21.  Seems like an obvious solution but I wouldn't have thought of it without this thread.  The solution to delete and restore the existing version did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have Nuget Package Manager installed.
By default, Visual Studio 2010 doesn't have it (later versions do)
 - Open Tools / Extension Manager
 - Search for Nuget Package Manager and click Download
 - After this I had to remove the Nuget package (Microsoft.Bxl.Async, Microsoft.BCL, and Microsoft.Bcl.Build) causing the error, restart VS and re-add the package.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didn't work for me. I just had to remove references (in packages and proj file) to Microsoft.Bcl.Build.. Rebuilt and succeeded.